# Better way for "refresh" and "setSelection" after Update ListView (android)

Tags: android, listview

In my `ListView`, I choose an Item to "Add Favorite" and I have to do some stuff work, I fill data again to refresh the List, then I implement `OnScrollListener` use `setSelection(firstVisibleItem)` to set List display right on Item was added.

Are there any better way to do that. I mean like `mCursor.requery()` or something like that in android APIs ? Or any suggest way?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question; I have a similar problem

Answer (score 5):

To display the selected item rather at the middle than at the top of my `ListView`, I used `setSelectionFromTop()`:

```
getListView().setSelectionFromTop(pos, getListView().getHeight() / 2);
```

Of course you could additionally subtract half of your cell layout's height from the division above to get the selection exactly in the middle.

Comment: Dividing the height by two will not center the item but make the top start halfway down giving a feeling of putting the item lower in the list. I usually subtract half a row height, or divide by 2.5 or 3 if the view height is hard to establish.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `requery()` is the preferred way to repopulate a `ListView` that is backed by a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Calling `setSelection()` on the `ListView` seems like a fine way to ensure the desired item is visible. I am unclear what the `OnScrollListener` has to do with any of this.

Comment: I had to think about the OnScrollListener, too! :-)

But I **guess** what's meant here is that by using this listener and remembering the last value that came through `firstVisibleItem` and using **this** value when repositioning, everything looks identical after updating the data!

Answer (score 1):

If you just call `setSelection()`, that will make your item display in **unnaturally**. For example, If your item is visible at the 'middle' of the screen and its position is 8. When you *add favorite*, *refresh data*, setSelection(8) the Item will display on 'top' of the screen (rather it is in the 'middle').

So, that why I use `OnScrollListener` to get `firstVisibleItem` and use this value to set position. It makes the item display naturally. This is the function:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int VisibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){}
```

I think It happens frequently with anyone who updates data in `ListView`. And I hope someone can share experience in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
mListActivity.runOnUiThread(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            x.setSelection(x.getCount());
        } 
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you all are looking:

```
onResume()
{
    refresh_your_data()
    if(listview.getadapter()==null)
     // create the adapter
    }
    else
    {
        adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
    }
}
```